# Season (i.e. summer/winter) dependent hyperlinks

Tags: jquery, date, hyperlink, momentjs

How can a hyperlink be created which goes to a different end point during the summer (i.e. `https://example.net/summer`) and during the winter (i.e. `https://example.net/winter`)?  Needs to be done client side only without PHP, etc.  Assume summer is from 4/15 to 9/15 and winter is from 9/16 to 4/14, however, exact dates are not important and can be slightly changed if easier.

EDIT.  I can't really take credit for this solution because `moment()` recommendation wa provided by Quentin Roger.

```
<a id="link" href="javascript:void(0)">Click Me</a>

$("#link").click(function() {
    window.location = moment().isBetween(moment("2017-05-01"), moment("2017-09-01"))
    ?'https://example.net/summer'
    :'https://example.net/winter';
});
```

Comment: just a hint: it will be unreliable to do this only with the client's date, because it can be set at wrong values. You should use a custom server script or any API or service to retreive a reliable date

Comment: @Kaddath  True, but this is acceptable.  Winter pages will have links back to summer and the same from summer to winter, and the purpose is only to get them initially to the page which we "think" is the right page.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for what you have tried.

Comment: @AlanLarimer  See bottom of original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do some date comparison before setting the href property

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let anchor = document.getElementById("season_dependant");
  // Get current Date:
  let date = new Date();
  
  // consider two dates as boundaries, they must be the same year
  let start_date = new Date();
  start_date.setMonth(3); // month index (-1)
  start_date.setDate(15); // day of month
  // => 15th, April of current year
  
  let end_date = new Date();
  end_date.setMonth(9); // month index (-1)
  end_date.setDate(1); // day of month
  // => 1st, October of current year
  
  // NOTE: must be start_date < end_date for this to work
  
  if (date > start_date && date < end_date) {
    // If inside period:
    anchor.href = "/summer";
  } else {
    // If outside period:
    anchor.href = "/winter";
  }
});
```

```html
<a id="season_dependant">link</a>
```

Comment: Nice native JavaScript solution

Comment: Never used `let` before.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: @user1032531 if you don't care about browser compatibility, you should not use var anymore. Instead use `let` and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: I previously had never heard of `let`.  Will do.  Also, your solution doesn't hard code the year.  Thanks!

Comment: yes I didn't set the year so that every instance of Date have the same year (the current one). If I did you would have to update your script every year

Comment: OR you can explicitly set the same year to every instances of Date

Answer (score 1):

I think I misunderstood something, but if you want to update a link depending on a condition based on date. You can do the following (using momentjs).
I let you improve the condition to determine if you are in the summer or not ;)

```
if (moment().isBetween(moment("2017-05-01"),moment("2017-09-01"))) {
  $("#link").attr('href', "https://example.net/summer").html('summer');
} else {
  $("#link").attr('href', "https://example.net/winter").html('winter');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ubdxLeb9/1/

Comment: Thanks.  I  didn't know about `moment()`.

Comment: No problem, momentjs is a very good library for browser compatibility. Happy to help.